# How to update user info with specific field in mongodb using node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was having some issues with my code today. I am trying to build a user profile setting, where the user can change their info. My problem stands as follows:

When I update a specific field like the username, I don't want other fields to be updated i.e. the email, the first name, and the last name. The username and the email have a unique attribute in the database, and if the user tries to change the username, it shows the email error saying even tho the user doesn't want to update the email.

So, how can I change the username without affecting other fields?

Thank you for your time.

**Node.js**

```
import User from '../model/user.js'
import verify from "../auth/verifyToken.js"

router.put("/user/account/change-user-info", verify,async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, username, email } = req.body

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne(req.user)

    // ------------ Firstname validation ------------ //
    if (!firstName || firstName.length < 2 || typeof firstName !== "string")
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage:
          "Firstname and should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!",
      })
    user.firstName = firstName


    // ------------ Lastname Validation ------------ //
    if (!lastName || lastName.length < 2 || typeof LastName !== "string")
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage:
          "Lastname should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!",
      })
    user.lastName = lastName


    // ------------ Email Validation ------------ //
    const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!email || typeof email !== "string" || !email.match(emailRegex))
      return res.status(400).json({ status: "error", massage: "Invalid email" })
    else if (emailExists) <------ Problem here
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Email already in use." })
    user.email = email


    // ------------ Username Validation --- Problem here ------------//
    const usernameExist = await User.findOne({ username })
    if (!username || typeof username !== "string" || !username.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$"))
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Invalid username." })
    else if (usernameExist) <------ Problem here
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Username is already taken." }) 
    user.username = username

    await user.save()

    res.status(201).json({
      status: "ok",
      massage: "Fields updated successfully!",
    })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

**Mongoose**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose"

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 45,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 2,
      max: 45,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 6,
      max: 45,
      unique: true,
    },
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      min: 8,
      max: 100,
    },
    avatar: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamp: true }
)

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema)

export default User
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user makes a request for changing their details, check for each property to see if it is changed, then do not send not changed properties the database

```
import User from '../model/user.js'
import verify from "../auth/verifyToken.js"

router.put("/user/account/change-user-info", verify,async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, username, email } = req.body

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne(req.user)

    var updated;

    // ------------ Firstname validation ------------ //
    if (!firstName || firstName.length < 2 || typeof email !== "string")
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage:
          "Firstname and should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!",
      })
    // checking if the first name has been changed
    if (user.firstName !== firstName) {
        updated.firstName = firstName
    }


    // ------------ Lastname Validation ------------ //
    if (!lastName || lastName.length < 2 || typeof email !== "string")
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage:
          "Lastname should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!",
      })
    // checking if the last name has been changed
    if (user.lastName !== lastName) {
        updated.lastName = lastName
    }


    // ------------ Email Validation ------------ //
    const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/
    const emailExists = await User.findOne({ email })

    if (!email || typeof email !== "string" || !email.match(emailRegex))
      return res.status(400).json({ status: "error", massage: "Invalid email" })
    else if (emailExists) <------ Problem here
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Email already in use." })
    // checking if the email has been changed
    if (user.email !== email) {
        updated.email = email
    }

    // ------------ Username Validation --- Problem here ------------//
    const usernameExist = await User.findOne({ username })
    if (!username || typeof username !== "string" || !username.match("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*$"))
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Invalid username." })
    else if (usernameExist) <------ Problem here
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ status: "error", massage: "Username is already taken." }) 
    // checking if the username has been changed
    if (user.username !== username) {
        updated.username= username
    }

    // updated variable only contains the updated fields, sending it too the database may solve the problem
    Asset.findOneAndUpdate(req.user, updated, 
    function (updatedUsed) {
        res.status(201).json({
          status: "ok",
          massage: "Fields updated successfully!",
        })
    } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
    })
```

**please check if i have made any typing errors**

Answer (score 0):

```
import User from '../model/user.js';
import verify from "../auth/verifyToken.js";
import _ from lodash;

router.put("/user/account/change-user-info", verify,async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, username, email } = req.body;

  // check validation check
  if (!_.isNil(firstName) && (firstName.length < 2 || typeof email !== "string")) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage: "Firstname and should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!"
      })
   }

   if (!_.isNil(lastName) && (lastName.length < 2 || typeof email !== "string")) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage: "LastName and should not be empty or should be at least 2 characters long!"
      })
   }

   const emailRegex = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
   if (!_.isNil(email) && (typeof email !== "string" || !email.match(emailRegex)) {
      return res.status(401).json({
        status: "error",
        massage: "Invalid email"
      })
   }

   // after the basic validation, now check the data from the database
   try {
      const userEmail = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!_.isEmpty(userEmail)) {
        return res.status(401).json({
           status: "error",
           message: "Email already in use"
        });
      }

      const userNameExist = await User.findOne({ username });
      if (!_.isEmpty(userNameExist)) {
        return res.status(401).json({
           status: "error",
           message: "Username is already taken."
        })
      }

      // update the database
      await User.updateOne({_id: req.session.userId}, {req.body});
      res.status(201).json({
         status: "ok",
         message: "Fields updated successfully!",
      })
    } catch (e) {
       console.log(e)
    }
}
```